# Let's get critical: Apr 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I Want to say that I am very impressed with the question quality here. I have been involved with several beta's and the quality of our first site assessment questions is great.  The signal to noise ratio here is incredibly high.  Now if we can just get some more users involved and generate more questions of this quality this site should take off!

Comment: I think content wise we are doing pretty well.  The big issue is that that of promotion.  We need more users with more quality questions so we can build more content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Long-term sustainability concerns of compact flourescent vs incandescent light bulbs](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/343/long-term-sustainability-concerns-of-compact-flourescent-vs-incandescent-light-b)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Non toxic insect(ant) repellent for use in the kitchen](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/412/non-toxic-insectant-repellent-for-use-in-the-kitchen)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What is a permaculture solution for dealing with deer in a suburban environment?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/357/what-is-a-permaculture-solution-for-dealing-with-deer-in-a-suburban-environment)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What are the environmental effects of discarding radioactive smoke detectors?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/512/what-are-the-environmental-effects-of-discarding-radioactive-smoke-detectors)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [What is the least dusty Earthen Plaster mixture to use on interior walls?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/364/what-is-the-least-dusty-earthen-plaster-mixture-to-use-on-interior-walls)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Are there any laws that prohibit composting of human waste in US cities?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/539/are-there-any-laws-that-prohibit-composting-of-human-waste-in-us-cities)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Is my car more sustainable with or without an EGR?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/390/is-my-car-more-sustainable-with-or-without-an-egr)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How far had Iceland gone by 2012 in decarbonising its energy system?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/439/how-far-had-iceland-gone-by-2012-in-decarbonising-its-energy-system)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Buying used or self-assembly furnitures when expecting to move frequently](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/540/buying-used-or-self-assembly-furnitures-when-expecting-to-move-frequently)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [What is the relationship between recycling and sustainability?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/452/what-is-the-relationship-between-recycling-and-sustainability)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)